# iframe resource interpreted as document but transferred with mime type application/vnd.ms-excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing asp.net mvc 5 web application using c#. I am trying to display excel file in iframe

```
<iframe src="../../Data/ExcelSheets/ProjectExpenditureDetails/20170917184328709.xls" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

When page loading always download the excel file and it is not displaying on the iframe.

Web developer tool says: resource interpreted as document, but transferred with mime type application/vnd.ms-excel

I don't know my approach is correct or not. If it's correct how to solve my problem. If it's wrong what is the best way to display excel file in web page.

Comment: I've never seen this before. What behavior are you hoping to achieve with this?

Comment: my client has bank statement as a excel sheet. so he wants to upload that excel to server and display on web page. @Locke125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do this natively in a browser. There are likely plugins that would allow it, but on a web site you can't guarantee someone will have that installed. I believe third party services are able to provide a some javascript that allows you to open a document. Google docs does something like this.

Think about flash applications (that used to be a thing). They contained proprietary code that wouldn't run in a browser without a plugin installed. XLS files are similar. There are some exceptions, but mostly a browser can only be expected to understand html, css, javascript, and a number of image formats. Even PDFs require a plugin to view, you just don't see it very often because many browsers make that fairly seamless now.

Unfortunately if you want to do this through a web site that needs to be secure I believe the route to go is actually replacing the shared sheet with application based functionality. Your clients may feel more comfortable about moving to google docs based sheets, which can be shared, but mine wouldn't touch it with a 10 foot pole. I'm not sure it is warranted, but that is how they feel.

Comment: I'll look for new approach. @Locke125 your advice is so helpful for me.